# Работа с текстом: удаление и вставка

Tags: php

Предположим есть строка:

```
$str = '0123456789';
```

Что нужно: удалить символы с позицией `2-4` (2,3,4 - это позиция а не часть строки) и вместо них вставить строку: `'!!'`.

Результирующая строка:

```
$str = '01!!56789';
```

Сразу скажу что хотелось бы услышать оптимальный вариант, существует ли такой или нет (*может есть уже функция реализующая подобное*).

Накостылять я и сам могу :) Но в любом случае, любое адекватное предложение плюсану.

Comment: если цифры заранее известны, то str_replace. Иначе preg_replace.

Comment: @Эдуард хотелось бы сразу уточнить, видимо забыл.

Comment: 2-4 это номера, а не принадлежность к тексту

Comment: но эти же номера записаны  в строке? А для функций разницы нет, какие символы в строке.

Comment: @Эдуард ну такую строку возможно я неудачно привел, но может быть такая строка: 'qwertyuiop', и нужно отсюда 2-4 символы заменить на другую строку, а какие это символы - не известно, известна только позиция

Comment: тогда наверное только preg_replace.

Comment: имхо, это более понятно, чем регулярка:
$str[2] = '!';
$str[3] = '!';
$str[4] = '!';

Answer (score 0):

Шаблон: `'~(?<=\w{2})\w{3}(\w*)~'`, где `(?<=\w{2})` - поиск позиции *(слева от нужной позиции 2 символа)*; `\w{3}` - 3 заменяемых символа; `(\w*)` - оставшаяся часть строки.

```
$str = 'qwertyuiop';

$pattern = '~(?<=\w{2})\w{3}(\w*)~';
$replace = '!!$1';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str);

// qw!!yuiop
```

Comment: @Manitikyl мой ответ удалить?

Comment: да пусть уж будет, людям может пригодится :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот походу идеальная функция, которая мне нужна.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr-replace.php